# Peaks up to N kilometers from borders (Overpass)

Tags: overpass-api

I'm trying to extract peaks that are within and up to say 100 kilometers away from country boundaries. The second part is however what I cannot get right.

How to query for nodes up to N kilometers away from an area in Overpass Turbo?

Answer (score 2):

The following query asks for peaks up to 5 kms away from the Pilsen borders, and still within the Pilsen area.

```
rel[name="Plzeň"][type=boundary][boundary=administrative][admin_level=8]->.rel;
.rel out geom;         // show boundary for illustration
.rel map_to_area;      // convert rel to area

node(area)(around.rel:5000)[natural=peak];
out;
```

Try it in overpass turbo! http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/zYR